# C++ function object terminology functor, deltor, comparator, etc

Tags: c++, terminology

Is there a commonly accepted terminology for various types for common functors?

For instance I found myself naturally using comparator for comparison functors like this:

```
struct ciLessLibC : public std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool> {
    bool operator()(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) const {
        return strcasecmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str()) < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
};
```

Or using the term deltor for something like this:

```
struct DeleteAddrInfo { 
    void operator()(const addr_map_t::value_type &pr) const {
        freeaddrinfo(pr.second);
    }
};
```

If using these kinds of shorthand terms is common, it there some dictionary of them all someplace?

Comment: What I know for sure is that there is no English word 'comparitor', there is a word 'comparator'.

Comment: I'd call your "deltor" a "deleter" informally.

Comment: @bobah:  Seriously, just edit the post to correct a spelling mistake, don't comment about it.

Answer (score 3):

Comparator is fairly widely used, more so in Java than C++ - comparison function being the  terminology in the original STL, Comparator the terminology in the Java API.

'deltor' isn't a word in common use, and sounds like 'delta', so wouldn't make me think of something which frees pointers.

Comment: I believe the common terms are "ctor" and "dtor" for constructor/destructor.

Comment: @PeterK I believe the common terms are "constructor" and "destructor" for constructor/destructor. I don't normally write or document my code in txt speak.

Comment: Any suggestions?  Delator maybe?

Comment: @Robert "deleter" would be a more common English construction for 'one who deletes'.  A 'delator' was the accusing party in Roman law, and still exists as one who delates (accuses). It's not normal to change the vowels in word stems in English; it often changes the meaning of the word.

Answer (score 2):

1. A function that takes two arguments and evaluates to a boolean is a ["binary predicate"](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BinaryPredicate.html) (likewise, "unary" for one argument, and "ternary" for three).
2. In the second case, "deleter" seems to be an acceptable name (see [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)).

Comment: +1 for the Boost reference.  In regards to the predicate terminology, I'm aware it and looking for more specific short hand terms like the "deleter" you mentioned which imply the functionality of the functor.

Answer (score 1):

Surely there are no standards, common rules applies.

Comment: What I'm wondering is if there is a list of commonly used functor terms anywhere?  No standards implied...